# the data output is horizontal from the following code, can it possbile to vertical

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the data output is horizontal from the following code, can it possbile to vertical, many thanks !

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url1 = "url"

content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1,"lxml")

div = soup.find("form", {"name": "SelHorse"})
rows = div.findAll('table')[6].findAll('tr')

for row in rows:
    print (row.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all `td` tags and then use `str.join`.

**Ex:**

```
for row in rows:
    if row:
        print( " ".join(td.text.strip() for td in row.findAll("td") if td) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your print statement:

```
print ((row.text).strip())
```

This will remove the new-line characters in your input and hence your output will not have blank lines in between.

For the commas what you can do is this:

```
for row in rows:
    print ((row.text).strip() + ",")
```

Note: this will print "," even in the last line. To avoid that just print that line separately. i.e. outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Every individual print statement in your for loop will create a new line. If you want to write everything in one line (I assume that's what you mean), you have to gather everything in one string. Replace your for-loop with the following:

```
output = ''
for row in rows:
    output += row
print row
```